# Add multi text to back every line

Tags: text, notepad++

i need help. i want to add text like this,
here is multi text i said

```
XBv77h%U
DR?EIuZ0
Ah%z#M04
@!LDh9Mo
...
...
```

here is text that i want to add 4 lines above at their back

```
username1;username1@myMxDomain.com;
username2;username2@myMxDomain.com;
username3;username3@myMxDomain.com;
username4;username4@myMxDomain.com;
...
...
```

so correct format will be

```
username1;username1@myMxDomain.com;XBv77h%U
username2;username2@myMxDomain.com;DR?EIuZ0
username3;username3@myMxDomain.com;Ah%z#M04
username4;username4@myMxDomain.com;@!LDh9Mo
...
...
```

currently i have notepad++ in my pc.
Thank you my english might be bad.

Comment: Without a line number already in your data I'm not sure this is possible with regex alone.

Comment: what isline number? sorry im noob

Comment: Regex in Notepad++ can't generate the _numbers_ you are assigning to the users.  I think you will end up writing a short script to handle this.

Comment: ok i understand now about username they are at front of the line it is not problem because i can use username generator on them

Comment: What is a username generator?

Comment: i mean i can do like type username at every lines first ex. Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4 and i use \r to add domain after that

Comment: or if there is any text program can do Specfic select text tell me

Comment: This would be pretty easy to handle in Excel.  There you could generate the username sequence and just piece together the output you want.

Comment: so i can add text like i said in thread with excel?

Comment: Of course you can try with Excel - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39430063/1981088

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge 2 text files into one, same lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403885/merge-2-text-files-into-one-same-lines)